# Is it possible to find more details on svv_vacuum_progress status Failed jobs in RedShift?

Tags: redshift, autovacuum

Running `SELECT * FROM svv_vacuum_progress` returns...

| table_name | status | time_remaining_estimate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| foo_table | Failed |  |

The table appears to be most recent in `stl_vacuum`, but they're marked as completed:

| status |
| --- |
| [VacuumBG] Finished |
| [VacuumBG] Started Delete Only |

Looking at `STL_QUERY`, everything appears to execute normal, which makes me think that maybe the information in `svv_vacuum_progress` isn't from the same query, but I have no way of really finding out how `svv_vacuum_progress` populates.

Is there anything I can do here to work my way backwards?